# What is this error?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class TaroGrid{
public:
    int getNumber(vector<string> grid)
    {
        int n = grid.size(), max = 0, count = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (grid[i][j] == grid[i - 1][j]) count++;
                else count = 1;
                if (count > max) max = count;
            }
        }
        return max;
    };
};


int main()
{
    TaroGrid test;
    vector<string> cool;
    int t = test.getNumber(cool);
    cout << "The largest number of cells Taro can choose is:  " << t <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your code did not compile:

errors linking:

```
TaroGrid-stub.o:In function `main':
   TaroGrid-stub.cc:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
TaroGrid.o:
   TaroGrid-stub.cc:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What are you linking with?

Comment: Show us how you're building.

Answer (score 2):

You've compiled `TaroGrid-stub.cc` twice, naming the object files differently `TaroGrid-stub.o` and `TaroGrid.o`.  These two objects are mostly identical (they might be different versions of the same code).  They definitely both have a `main` function.

Then you passed both objects to the linker, which can't decide which is the real `main`.

There are a couple possible solutions.

1. Delete the old object file.
2. Don't link with `*.o`, but actually name the specific object files you intend to use.